# How to apply the log sum exp trick on the following expression?

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, computer-science

I am an electrical engineer who is currently working with some probability problem. In my expression, I experience some numerical error for large $m$ and $n$ and dont now how to overcome it. Paritcularly for evaluating this expression.

$m\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n ( 1 - {(1 - kq{p^{n - 1}})^{m - 1}})\left( \begin{array}{c}
n\\
k
\end{array} \right){q^k}{p^{n - k}}$

Where $p$ is a probability and $q=1-p$ and the varibles $m$ and $n$ are both positive integers.

I have a guts feeling that this maybe possible through the use of the log sum exp trick because the expression in the summation is just a bunch of things multiply together but I do not know how.

Would you kindly help me with this.

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: How large is your $m$ and $n$? Is your $p$ very close to $0$ or $1$?

Comment: M  and n may be 100 200 but p is not  close to 0 or 1. However I would happy if there is a way to approximate in the case of p close to 0 , close to 1 or p from 0.2 to 0.8

Comment: The result is deep inside the representational range of IEEE double precision. What numerical error are you experiencing? How are you evaluating the factorials?